# Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для записи. this->_Myproxy было 0x110FC90

Tags: c++, файлы, исключения, память, списки

Здравствуйте, написал функцию загрузки структур из бинарного файла, и добавление их в динамический список

```
void download_data_from_file(string file_name, list* list_to_save)
{
    if (list_to_save->head)
    {
        if (!error_message_yes_no("Внимание!!!", "Перезаписать данные?"))
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    free_memory(); //удаление динамического списка
    print_layout(); //вывод таблицы

    if (file_name.size() <= 4)
    {
        error_message("ОШИБКА", "Неправильное имя файла");
        return;
    }

    if ((file_name[file_name.size() - 4] != '.') &&
            (file_name[file_name.size() - 3] != 't') &&
            (file_name[file_name.size() - 2] != 'x') &&
            (file_name[file_name.size() - 1] != 't'))
    {
        error_message("ОШИБКА", "Неверное имя файла, необходим txt формат");
        return;
    }

    file_name[file_name.size() - 3] = 'D';
    file_name[file_name.size() - 2] = 'A';
    file_name[file_name.size() - 1] = 'T';
    ifstream fin(file_name, ios::in | ios::_Nocreate | ios::binary);

    if (!fin)
    {
        error_message("Ошибка!!!", " Ошибка открытия файла");
        return;
    }

    node::data_struct temp;

    while (fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp),
                    sizeof(node::data_struct)))
    {
        add_node(temp, &Main_list);
    }

    error_message("Внимание!!!", " Загрузка успешно завершена");
    fin.close();
    return;
}

void add_node(node ::data_struct& data, list* main_list)
{
    node* temp = new node;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = nullptr;

    if (!main_list->head)
    {
        main_list->ACTIVE_ELEMENT_PTR  = main_list->FIRST_PAGE_ELEMENT_PTR =
                                             main_list->head = main_list->tail = temp;
        main_list->ACTIVE_ELEMENT = main_list->FIRST_PAGE_ELEMENT = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        main_list->tail->next = temp;
        temp->prev = main_list->tail;
        main_list->tail = temp;
    }

    main_list->ELEMENTS_NUM++;

    if (main_list->NOW_ELEMENTS_ON_PAGE < ELEMENTS_ON_PAGE)
        print_node(data, main_list->NOW_ELEMENTS_ON_PAGE + 1, false,
                   main_list);
}
```

Структура элемента списка

```
    struct node { 
        struct data_struct { 
            string course,      // номер курса
                   group_num,   // шифр группы 
                   subject_num, // шифр предмета  
                   A_marks,           // отличные оценки
                   B_marks,           // хорошие оценки
                   C_marks,           // удовлетворительные оценки
                   D_marks,           // плохие оценки
                   missed_lections,   // пропущенных лекций
                   missed_labs;      // пропущенных лабораторных
        } data;

    node* next = nullptr;    // указатель на следующей элемент
    node* prev = nullptr;  // указатель на предыдущий элемент
};
struct list {
    node* head = nullptr;
    node* tail = nullptr;
    node* ACTIVE_ELEMENT_PTR = nullptr;
    node* FIRST_PAGE_ELEMENT_PTR = nullptr;

    int ELEMENTS_NUM = 0;
    int ACTIVE_ELEMENT = 0;
    int PAGE = 1;
    int NOW_ELEMENTS_ON_PAGE = 0;
    int FIRST_PAGE_ELEMENT = 0;
};
```

`"Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для записи. this->_Myproxy было 0x110FC90."`
 или

```
"Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения._Pnext было 0x1140264."
```

вылезает после того, как данные загружены, и вызывается return...
В дополнение кидаю функцию добавления элементов в список, и структуру элемента

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одного

```
node::data_struct temp;
while (fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp), sizeof(node::data_struct)))
```

при том, что в структуре есть `string`:

```
struct data_struct { 
    string course,      // номер курса
```

вполне достаточно, чтоб ничего не работало. Вот так, прямо можно (с определенными ограничениями) читать только POD - plain old data, но что толку читать `string`, внутри которого есть указатель на выделенную память, например? Вы считываете нечто, что трактуется как указатель на память, к которому потом попытается обратиться программа...

Далее разбираться не стал.

Comment: Спасибо, а не могли бы вы подсказать как в данном случае правильно считать данные, пожалуйста, и как сохранить, так как там я делал также...?

Comment: Ну, нужно при сохранении сохранять содержимое строки, я бы, раз файл бинарный, указывал сначала длину, потом ее содержимое. При чтении - читал бы длину, потом саму строку и из нее создавал `string`. Словом, разрабатывайте свой формат файла :), и следуйте ему при записи и чтении. Хранить нужно только данные, но не указатели на них.